# How to write the constraint (A + B <= 1) in DOcplex?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex, docplex

I am new to DOcplex. I have two binary decision variables A and B and I wish to write the constraint (A+B <=1). I tried to write the constraint using "+" operator but it does not work.

Here is the code that causes the error at run-time:

```
A= {mdl.binary_var(name="A")}

B= {mdl.binary_var(name="B")}

mdl.add_constraint(A+B<=1)
```

And this is the error:

Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set'

Comment: The error means what it says: you're trying to add two set literals. So get rid of your `{}` braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='my model')

A= mdl.binary_var(name="A")

B= mdl.binary_var(name="B")

mdl.add_constraint(A+B<=1)



mdl.solve()


print("A = ",A.solution_value)
print("B = ",B.solution_value)
```

works fine